# Auth with CAS, redirect after Login, Laravel

Tags: laravel, cas

I have my authentication with cas, and I try to redirect a user on my app after the login is made, and when he logout to a page from app. The problem is that works just 1/2.

1) -> after login the redirect is correct, but on logout skip my page and redirect to cas(url: /)

2) -> logout is redirecting ok, but on login didn't redirect to my app and I get this message:(url: /login)

> You, user, have successfully logged into the Central Authentication
>   Service. However, you are seeing this page because CAS does not know
>   about your target destination and how to get you there. Examine the
>   authentication request again and make sure a target
>   service/application that is authorized and registered with CAS is
>   specified.

```
CAS_HOSTNAME=cas.example.co
CAS_REAL_HOSTS=cas.example.co
CAS_LOGOUT_REDIRECT=http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
CAS_REDIRECT_PATH=http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
CAS_CONTROL_SESSIONS=false
CAS_VALIDATE_CN=false
CAS_ENABLE_SAML=false
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/logout', function() {

    if( cas()->isAuthenticated() ) {

        auth()->logout();
        session()->flush();
        request()->session()->getHandler()->destroy(request()->session()->getId());
        cas()->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    } else {
        session()->flush();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'cas.guest'],function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@index');
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Where do u add the CAS_REDIRET_PATH?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `service` parameter to both `/login`and `/logout` endpoints, in order to instruct CAS to redirect users to the specified service url after a successful login/logout.

So assuming that the CAS server is available on `https://cas.example.com`, the login/logout urls should be as follows:

**Login:**

`https://cas.example.com/login?service=https://myservice.example.com`

**Logout:**

`https://cas.example.com/logout?service=https://myservice.example.com`

<sub>**On both cases service urls should be escaped.**</sub>

**Another option** would be to define default redirect urls for login/logout endpoints on CAS server configuration. This way there is not need to provide `service` parameter to aforesaid endopoints. Find below the corresponding properties:

```
cas.logout.redirectUrl=your_service_url
cas.view.defaultRedirectUrl=your_service_url
```

Note: Regarding logout redirect url, by default CAS does not allow redirects on logout. To alter this behavior, you should enable `cas.logout.followServiceRedirects` property. More [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/configuration/Configuration-Properties.html#logout).

On above recommendations, I assume that you have **full access** to CAS server.